# Page collapses when useEffect() is called for the second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I'm using `useContext()` to pass an idea of selected movie to a React component. I'm using  `useEffect()` to fetch data about that movie for the first time the React page (component) is rendered and this works.

However, if the page is reloaded, it crashes and the error is shown:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

[image]

MoviePage.tsx

```
import {useState, useEffect, useContext} from "react";
import Topbar from '../Header/Topbar';
import { fetchSelectedMovie } from "../../services/movies.service";
import {Grid, Card, CardMedia, Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import noImage from '../../images/no-image-available.png';
import { MoviesContext } from "../../services/context";
import './Pages.css';
const posterBaseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300";
interface Genre {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  vote_average: number;
  overview: string;
  poster_path?: string;
  release_date: string;
  budget: number;
  revenue: number;
  genres: Genre[];
}

const MoviePage = (props: any) => {

  const { selectedMovie } = useContext(MoviesContext);

  const [movieImg, setMovieImg] = useState<string>(noImage);
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>(
    {
      id: 0,
      title: '',
      vote_average: 0,
      overview: '',
      poster_path: noImage,
      release_date: '',
      budget: 0,
      revenue: 0,
      genres: [],
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const callAPI = async () => {
      const fetchedMovieInfo = await fetchSelectedMovie(Number(selectedMovie));
      setMovie(fetchedMovieInfo);
      setMovieImg(posterBaseUrl+fetchedMovieInfo.poster_path);
    }

    callAPI();
  }, [selectedMovie]);

  return (
    <>
      <Topbar></Topbar>
      <Grid container spacing={2} className="container-movie-page">
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Card className="card">
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt={"Poster of " + movie.title}
              image={movieImg}
              title={movie.title}
            />
          </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={9} className="align-left">
          <h1 className="title">
            {movie.title}
          </h1>
          <div className="content">
            <span className="rating-container">
              {movie.vote_average}
            </span>
            <div>
              {movie.release_date}
            </div>
            <p className="content-main-paragraph">
              {movie.overview}
            </p>
            <p>
              Genres:&nbsp;
                {movie.genres.map((genre, i) => (
                  <span key={i}>
                    {genre.name},&nbsp;
                  </span>
                ))}
            </p>
            <p>
              Budget: ${movie.budget}
            </p>
            <p>
              Revenue: ${movie.revenue}
            </p>
            <Button 
              variant="contained" 
              color="primary" 
              href="#">
               sth
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          CAST HERE (carrousel to scroll horiz)
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default MoviePage;
```

movies.service.tsx

```
export async function fetchSelectedMovie (currentMovieId: number ) {
  return await fetch(
    `${movieApiBaseUrl}/movie/${currentMovieId}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((body) => {return body})
    .catch(() => {
        return {};
    });
}
```

Do you know what's the issues?

Comment: I'm guessing that `movie.genres` has not been defined for one of the movies you are loading. You should do a basic null check before attempting to map it. Dealers choice how you do it some examples might be: `{movie.genres && movie.genres.map(/* etc */)}` or `{movie.genres?.map(/* etc */)}`

Comment: Thanks! The page doesn't crash anymore, however, I get the errors `movies.service.tsx:15 GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/0?api_key=f13446aa3541ebd88cf65b91f6932c5b 404 ` and `GET https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300undefined 404` after the second reload. I assume, `useEffect()` should. be called only once somehow..?

Comment: You get 404 (not found) errors because your URLs point to inexistent endpoints. For the request to themoviedb.org your currentMovieId is 0, and as no movie with id 0 can be found you get a 404. For the request to tmdb.org fetchedMovieInfo.poster_path is undefined, hence you again end up requesting an object that doesn't seem to exist. You should make sure your data is consistent and verify it's validity (as you did with the genres) before fetching the data.